# Geological/tectonic/thermal/etc. implications of Rayleigh numbers ≥ 100,000,000

Tags: geology, terrestrial-planets

What's a Rayleigh number? Well, it doesn't have anything to do with [Rayleigh scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering). [Here's a Wikipedia page on this concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_number), but I believe Elvira Mulyukova's and David Bercovici's *[Mantle Convection in Terrestrial Planets](https://oxfordre.com/planetaryscience/display/10.1093/acrefore/9780190647926.001.0001/acrefore-9780190647926-e-109;jsessionid=E0978952D39C68EC05DEED914229758C)* put it better:

> The competition between forcing by thermal buoyancy and damping by
> viscosity and thermal diffusion is characterized by a dimensionless
> ratio called the Rayleigh number.

In other words, a [Rayleigh number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_number) represents the ratio between how much hot mass in a [convection current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection) rises and how much the [viscosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity) and [thermal conductivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conductivity) of the mass stop it from rising and bleed away its heat, respectively. In this case, the mass in question is the mantle of a terrestrial planet, and the convection current in question is [mantle convection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantle_convection).

*Mantle Convection in Terrestrial Planets* goes on to state the following:

> **$Ra$** [Rayleigh number] needs to exceed a certain value, called the
> critical Rayleigh number $Ra_c$, in order to excite
> convective flow. The value of $Ra_c$ is typically on the order of
> 1,000, with the exact value depending on the thermal and mechanical
> properties of the horizontal boundaries, (e.g., whether the boundary
> is rigid or open to the air or space, see [Chandrasekhar, 1961](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-fluid-mechanics/article/abs/hydrodynamic-and-hydromagnetic-stability-by-s-chandrasekhar-clarendon-press-oxford-university-press-1961-652-pp-5-5s/DC77FFB6F40A90109063FEAE444692BB)).

Therefore, it can be concluded that, if, within a body's mantle, the ratio of "stuff-forcing-its-way-up" to "stuff-being-held-down" is ≤ ~1,000, said body won't experience convective flow in its mantle. As far as I know, convective flow in the mantle is necessary for a body to have plate tectonics; this is supported by the fact that the Earth and Venus, with the highest Rayleigh numbers calculated here, are fairly volcanically active, whereas Mercury, with the lowest one, is a dead rock, and Mars, with the second-lowest one, features stagnant-lid tectonics, if I recall correctly.

Continuing from *Mantle Convection in Terrestrial Planets*:

> Assuming their material properties are similar to Earth’s, we can
> estimate the Rayleigh numbers for the mantles of other terrestrial
> planets: ${10}^4$ for Mercury, ${10}^7$ for Venus, and ${10}^6$ for Mars. With the
> exception of Mercury, whose $Ra$ is at most an order of magnitude above
> critical, the mantle of the rocky planets in the solar system appear
> to be cooling predominantly by convection.

Mulyukova and Bercovici calculated these Rayleigh numbers using the following values:

| Property | Mercury | Venus | Earth | Mars |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Density (kilograms per cubic meter)** | 3500 | 4000 | 4000 | 3500 |
| **Surface temperature (degrees Kelvin)** | 440 | 730 | 285 | 220 |
| **Core-mantle boundary temperature (degrees Kelvin)** | 3000 | 3500 | 3500 | 3000 |
| **Mantle thickness (kilometers)** | 400 | 2900 | 2900 | 2000 |
| **Gravity (meters per second squared)** | 3.7 | 10 | 10 | 3.5 |

The gravity values (if not others) are slightly inaccurate and could use slight refining (for instance, 9.80665 $m/s^2$ rather than 10 $m/s^2$ for the Earth's gravity), but that's irrelevant to this question.

For the purposes of this question, the equation for finding a Rayleigh number is: $Ra = \frac{ \rho g \alpha \Delta Td^3 }{\upsilon \kappa}$ where:

- $\rho$ = density of mantle
- g = planet's gravity
- $\alpha$ = [thermal expansivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_expansion) of mantle
- $\Delta T$ = difference in temperature between top and bottom boundaries of mantle
- *d* = thickness of mantle
- $\upsilon$ = viscosity of mantle
- $\kappa$ = [thermal diffusivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_diffusivity) of mantle

My question is: **what would the geology of a planet with a high (specifically, $Ra \geq 10^8$) Rayleigh number look like?** The few planets for which I can find calculated Rayleigh numbers seem to fit a trend in which higher Rayleigh numbers correlate to more volcanism, more mountain-forming, more tectonic plates moving about, etc. Obviously, a sample size of 4 doesn't allow itself to accurate extrapolations, but that's why you're here: I'm asking this in the hope that someone more informed and/or qualified can provide further insight.

Let's use four hypothetical planets here:

- $Ra = 10^8$
- $Ra = 10^9$
- $Ra = 10^{10}$
- $Ra = 10^{11}$

If any of these are physically impossible, let me know.

Even before this is answered, I think I can draw several conclusions myself. Such a planet would cool relatively faster than planets with low Rayleigh numbers (*how* much more quickly, and what the relationship between Rayleigh number and heat loss is, I don't know) as the convection currents within its mantle would carry heat away from its core more quickly. I think that this means that, if the Rayleigh number-to-surface-area ratio (and, therefore, the Rayleigh number-to-planetary-radius ratio) is greater than that of planets with equal surface areas and ratios, the [geothermal gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geothermal_gradient) would likely be steeper; more heat would be soaking out of the ground per unit of surface area. I also imagine such planets would see more volcanism, more mountain-forming, more tectonic plates moving about, etc.

I'm fairly sure this question fits Astronomy SE better than it fits Physics SE. If you think otherwise, let me know.

Comment: Kind of related: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/40769/34513

Comment: @Jean-MariePrival As a matter of fact, the answer to that post is the very thing which put me onto the concept of Rayleigh numbers in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(This is more an answer to this part: "If any of these are physically impossible, let me know".)

As you mention volcanism, plate tectonics, mountains... I make the assumption that you consider rocky planets only. If so, it is pretty straightforward to calculate the theoretical maximum Rayleigh number of a rocky planet. The rocks being essentially the same as those on Earth/Mars/Venus, parameters like $\alpha$, $\upsilon$, $\kappa$ and $\rho$ will be similar. That leaves us $g$, $\Delta T$ and $d$ to work with. They all work the same way: the bigger the planet, the bigger they are, and the bigger $Ra$ gets.

Now, according to the following graph, the largest rocky super-Earth (near the "67 % Fe" dashed grey line) has a mass of about 7 $M_E$ and a radius of about 2 $R_E$ (a bit lower, but let's say 2 for the sake of simplicity):

[image]
*Scatter plot of super-Earth characteristics in context showing the mass, $m$, and radius, $r$, for transiting Super-Earths (black dots), public domain*

This translates in:

- $g = 17.26 \approx$ 2 times that of the Earth
- $d^3 =$ 8 times that of the Earth
- $\Delta T$ is trickier, but is fairly linear in Earth's mantle, so extrapolating the trend yields ~6000 K, about 2 times that of the Earth

This back-of-the-envelope calculation shows that the largest *rocky* super-Earth can have a $Ra$ of about $3 \times 10^8$, no more.

As to how such a vigorous mantle convection would translate in terms of surface processes, I agree with you: probably more volcanism and plate movements. The tectonic regime could also be different: some people think that in the Archean (when the Earth likely had a higher $Ra$) the dynamics was more vertical, as opposed to the modern horizontal tectonic regime.

Comment: I think this is a very good heuristic for finding the largest possible Rayleigh number. I'll note, however: larger rocky bodies have been hypothesized. For instance, Kepler-277b may have 87.4 M⊕ and 2.92 R⊕, and Kepler-145b may have 37.1 M⊕ and 2.65 R⊕. However, these figures equate to densities roughly comparable to depleted uranium and lead, respectively, which seem overly large, so your predictions likely hold true for bodies *known* to be rocky. Honestly, that's an entirely different question I should ask Astronomy SE. Also, thanks for the edit; these symbols can be tricky to work with.

Comment: Did the math. If mass/radius figures are accurate, Kepler-277b has ~10.25⊕ g, 24.9⊕ d^3, and 2.92⊕ delta-T, for a Rayleigh number of ~7.45E9, and Kepler-145B has ~5.28⊕ g, 18.61⊕ d^3, and 2.65⊕ delta-T, for a Rayleigh number of ~2.604E9. Do you think such high numbers would equate to proportionately greater more volcanic and tectonic activity, though? At a certain point, it seems like it would be difficult for a planet to get more tectonically active and volcanic.

Comment: Are you sure of your calculations? According to Wikipedia, Kepler-277b has a very large iron core, of 2.435 $R_{\oplus}$. That leaves only 0.485 $R_{\oplus}$ of rocky, convective layer (i.e., mantle), or ~3000 km, like Earth. So $d^3$ and $\Delta T$ would be similar, leaving just a factor of 10 to account for $g$, yielding a $Ra$ of $10^8$.

Comment: And I agree, there is probably a limit, at some point things would probably stop being solid, so no more plate tectonics or volcanism, just a big magma ocean world.